# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and window.open returning null in a cross origin iframe even though it opened successfully

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, iframe, cross-origin-opener-policy

I have a case of where

- Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy is set to same-origin
- There is a cross domain iframe...
- ... and in the iframe I'm opening a popup/tab of a page on yet another domain using `window.open`

Then the return value of `window.open` is `null`, even though the tab opens successfully.

For example if

- I save the below in `main.py`
- Install fastapi, e.g. via `pip install fastapi`
- run `uvicorn main:app --reload --port 8000` and `uvicorn main:app --reload --port 8001`
- Visit http://localhost:8000/
- Click the "Open" button

Then a new tab opens showing the Google home page, but I'll see `null` in the console on the original tab.

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_root(response: Response):
    response.headers["Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy"] = "same-origin"
    return '''
        <iframe src="http://localhost:8001/iframe"></iframe>
    '''

@app.get("/iframe", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_iframe(response: Response):
    response.headers["Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy"] = "same-origin"
    return '''
        <button id="button">Open</button>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                const w = window.open('https://www.google.com/', "_blank");
                console.log(w);
            });
        </script>
    '''
```

However if I visit the iframe directly by going to `http://localhost:8001/iframe` and do the same thing, I see what seems to be a Window(/Window proxy?) object in the console.

Or: if I make the iframe be on the same domain as the parent page, I'll also see a Window/Window proxy object in the console.

Or: if I change `same-origin` to `same-origin-allow-popups`, I'll also see a Window/Window proxy object in the console.

Why in the case of a cross origin iframe with Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy set to same-origin does `window.open` return `null`? At https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open it says

> null is returned if the browser fails to open the new browsing context, for example because it was blocked by a browser popup blocker.

But it *did* open the browsing context...

The reasons why I want to understand: I have a similar setup on a site, and I'm deciding between `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-site` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-site-allow-popups`. So, I need to understand what it does. However, window.open's behaviour. depending on whether it's in a cross domain iframe or not is slightly thwarting that understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why in the case of a cross origin iframe with Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy set to same-origin does window.open return null?

It's in the spec. In this exact situation it makes `window.open` behave as though you passed `noopener` to it, which in turn makes window.open return null.

In more detail, from [The rules for choosing a navigable](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#the-rules-for-choosing-a-navigable)

> 3. If currentDocument's cross-origin opener policy's value is "same-origin" or "same-origin-plus-COEP", and currentDocument's origin is not same origin with currentDocument's relevant settings object's top-level origin, then:
>
>    1. Set noopener to true.
>    2. Set name to "_blank".
>    3. Set windowType to "new with no opener".

and then from [7.2.2.1 Opening and closing windows](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name), when it's describing what window.open does

> 14. If noopener is true or windowType is "new with no opener", then return null.

You can also see how `window.open` behaves with `noopener` - with no COOP and no iframe involved - it returns null just as in the case of this question.

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_root(response: Response):
    return '''
        <button id="button">Open</button>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                const w = window.open('https://www.google.com/', "_blank", "noopener");
                console.log(w);
            });
        </script>
    '''
```